# SharePoint 2010 User Profile Sync issue

Tags: user-profile, sharepoint-foundation, profile-sync

I am doing a SharePoint user profile sync from AD, the process is working fine, as shown in the screenshot below got from "Synchronization service manager" 2373 profiles were added.

[image]

but only 9 were added to SharePoint

[image]

i checked AD and found that the 9 accounts have type "USER" and others have "inetOrgPerson".
How can i add these marked as "inetOrgPerson" to SharePoint user profile??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to add InetOrgPerson to SharePoint 2010 Users Profiles on the below link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidrei/archive/2011/10/03/configuring-user-profile-services-synchronization-on-inetorgperson-object.aspx

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

2373 are added to the metaverse, then they must be push to MOSS ( next line in MIIS ) maybe you will see some veto

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Hi Fred; I still cant see any profile, i did full sync again but still not getting any profile. is there any way to tell sync service manager to migrate profiles with type InetOrgPerson??

Comment: Hi Guys, any updates on the above?

Comment: I need help guys :)